# How many phones can we take on a plane?

Tags: air-travel, airports, cellphones, turkey, england

How many phones can we take on a plane? I have 3 phones and an iPod. Would I be able to fly from England to Turkey and back?

Comment: Are you asking about how many you will be allowed on the plane with, or how many you can take into Turkey (and/or England)?

Comment: 3 Phones don't cause much trouble as long as they are for personal use and not for sale. i.e. unused/packed boxes

Comment: Ok thankyou and I'd that going to and from turkey